# Linear transformation for a null space involving a plane

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

For this question, I am asked to find a matrix in standard coordinates for the linear transformation below. My problem is that I can't seem to set it up properly.

> $T: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3 $ is a linear transformation with $T(0,0,-1)=(1,-1,1)$ and $Null([T])=\{(x,y,z)|2x+y-z=0\}$.

My understanding was that the matrix would simply be the following:

$$[T]=\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
    2 & 1 & -1 \\
    2 & 1 &  1 \\
    2 & 1 & -1 \\
  \end{array}\right]$$

Because when I multiply $$[T]=\left[\begin{array}{rrrr}
    2 & 1 & -1 \\
    2 & 1 &  1 \\
    2 & 1 & -1 \\
  \end{array}\right]$$ and $$\left[\begin{array}{r}
    0  \\
    0  \\
    -1 \\
  \end{array}\right]$$

I should get $$\left[\begin{array}{r}
    1  \\
    -1  \\
    1 \\
  \end{array}\right]$$

Am I even going about this the right way? If not, can someone suggest where I might be going wrong and help me out? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equation of the null space, $2x+y−z=0$, can be written $z= 2x+ y$ so that all vectors in that null space can be written as $$<x, y, 2x+ y>= <x, 0, 2x>+ <0, y, y>= x<1, 0, 2>+ y<0, 1, 1>$$

Writing the matrix $\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\ d & e & f\\ g & h & i\end{bmatrix}$  we must have $\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\ d & e & f\\ g & h & i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 0 \\ 2\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}a+ 2c \\ d+ 2f \\ g+ 2i\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$
so $a+ 2c= 0$, $d+ 2f= 0$, and $g+ 2i= 0$.

We must have $\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\ d & e & f\\ g & h & i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}b+ c \\ e+ f \\ h+ i\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 0 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$ so $b+ c= 0$, $e+ f= 0$, and $h+ i= 0$.

Finally, since $T(0, 0, -1)= (1, -1, 1)$ we must have 
$\begin{bmatrix}a & b & c \\ d & e & f\\ g & h & i\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}-c \\ -f \\ -i\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ -1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$
so we must have  $-c= 1$, $-f= -1$, and $-i= 1$.

So solve the 9 linear equations, $a+ 2c= 0$, $d+ 2f= 0$, $g+ 2i= 0$, $b+ c= 0$, $e+ f= 0$, $h+ i= 0$, $-c= 1$, $-f= -1$, and $-i= 1$ for the $9$ unknown values $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $e$, $f$, $g$, $h$, and $i$.

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not the right way because your matrix $T$ has rank $2$, so its null space is only one dimensional, and not a two-dimensional plane, as is required.

What you may want to do is to look for a matrix whose rank is $1$, and whose image contains the vector $(1,-1,1)$.

Comment: Sorry, how do you know that the rank of the null space has to be $2$ and why is that required?

And if the image contains $(1,-1,1)$, I'm not really sure how to manipulate the  $2x+y-z=0$ in that case.

Comment: There is a basic theorem in Linear algebra that says that the dimension of the null space plus the dimension of the image equals the dimension of the whole space. Since here the dimension of the null space is equal to $2$ (this is because $2x+y-z=0$ is an equation of a plane, as one learns in high school), it follows that the dimension of the image is $1$. There is another basic theorem in Linear Algebra that says that the rank of the matrix representing a linear transformation is equal to the dimension of the image.

Comment: Ohh right. I forgot that you need two vectors to span a plane. So yes the dimension of the null space would be $2$ and then $Rank(A)+Nullity(A)=3$.

Okay, that problem is rectified now. I'm still having some trouble setting up the matrix. I know the plane has to be present in the matrix somehow. Am I correct in saying that I have to manipulate the signs of the coefficients for the plane until I get that the rank is 1 and the consequently the nullity is 2 as required?

Comment: @FutureMathperson You can be much more systematic about this. Recall that the null space is the orthogonal complement of the row space. Can you find a vector that spans the row space?

Comment: Sure but to do that, I need a set of vectors. If I had that, I would then row reduce and and see where the leading ones are which would given me the basis for the row space of this transformation. My only question then I guess is what vectors would I pick? I guess I could use $(2,1,-1)$ for all three rows and find the row space from that but I'm not even sure if my approach is right.

Comment: @FutureMathperson It’s a rank-one matrix: the row space is one-dimensional and every row is a scalar multiple of the same vector.

Comment: I'm sorry for asking this, but why? Why is each row a scalar multiple of each other? Is it because the Null space is defined by the plane given by the normal $<2,1,-1>$ so any scalar multiple will also be a valid normal to that plane as well?

Answer (score 1):

You’ve satisfied the first condition, but the null space isn’t right: you have a rank-two matrix, which makes for a one-dimensional null space, but it needs to be two-dimensional.

So, the first condition requires that the matrix look like $$\begin{bmatrix}*&*&-1\\*&*&1\\*&*&-1\end{bmatrix},$$ as you’ve already worked out. Now recall that the null space is the orthogonal complement of the row space. From the defining equation of the required null space, we know that $(2,1,-1)$ spans it, so every row of the matrix must be a scalar multiple of this vector. I think that you can take it from here.

There’s also a brute-force approach that doesn’t take advantage of the specific characteristics of this problem. Observe that, with a suitable choice of bases, the matrix of $T$ is $\operatorname{diag}(1,0,0)$. The basis for the domain should consist of $(0,0,-1)$ and a pair of linearly-independent vectors that span the null space. The basis for the codomain needs to include $T(0,0,-1)$, and you can extend it to a basis for $\mathbb R^3$ in whatever way is convenient. Form the appropriate change-of-basis matrices and multiply it out.

Comment: Okay so I went ahead and found the basis for the row space. I get $\{s(-1/2,1,0),t(1/2,0,1)\}$. So I suppose I could get a $3 \times 3$ matrix for some choice of $s$ and $t$? However, the rank of such a matrix isn't $1$ which is a required condition.

Comment: @FutureMathperson How is the row space two-dimensional when the null space is also two-dimensional? You’ve computed a basis for the _null_ space. I already gave you a basis for the row space in this answer: it consists of the single vector $(2,1,-1)$.

Comment: I just edited my comment but that should not be the case. I was row reducing:

$\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
    2 & 1 & -1 \\
    2 & 1 & -1 \\
    2 & 1 & -1 \\
  \end{array}\right]$

since the row vectors could be any scalar multiple of each other.

Comment: @FutureMathperson Yes, and what was the result of that row-reduction? You should end up with one nonzero row, and that spans the row space. It seems that you keep confusing the row space and null space.

Comment: Yes sorry. That was my fault. That row reduction gives me a basis for the orthogonal compliment of the row space or equivalently, the null space of $[T]$. I was wondering how that would help though.

Comment: @FutureMathperson It also gives you a basis for the row space—the nonzero rows of the reduced matrix. It’s entirely unnecessary to go though this for this problem, though, since you can read the single row space basis vector from the equation $2x+y-z=0$. If you use the brute-force generic method that I outlined, then you will need a basis for the null space, but here, all you need is two independent vectors orthogonal to $(2,1,-1)$ and those can be generated by inspection.

Comment: Ahh fair. Yes I can do this by inspection and it's fairly straightforward if I can just guess and check but I guess I was trying to do it a more concrete way. I will investigate your 2nd method and see how it goes. Thanks a lot!